# how to apply separately online for tourist visa for UK for a family (Husband, Wife and Child)?

Tags: visas

I want to apply for tourist visa for UK along with my wife and son.  I am told that separate applications for each member be filed.  I used my email ID to complete my application.  Now I want to apply on behalf of my wife and son.  Should I use another email ID ?